# Use the ratio test to prove the convergence of $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Use the ratio test to prove the convergence of
>
> $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}$$

Well, I used the ratio test and, so far, I got $\dfrac{n^n}{n+1}$, which tends to infinity when $n$ tends to infinity. But the thing is that my teacher told me that the result is $\dfrac{1}{e}$. What happens?

Answer (score 5):

$$
\frac{(n+1)!/(n+2)^{n+1}}{n!/(n+1)^n}=\frac{(n+1)(n+1)^n}{(n+2)^{n+1}}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^{n+1}\underset{n\to+\infty}{\to}\textrm e^{-1}.
$$